# Cron выражение на каждые 3 дня

Tags: linux, cron

Хочу составить cron выражение которое будет срабатывать каждые три дня, если сделать так `0 8 */3 * *`, то это будет означать, что каждое 3 число месяца в 8:00 будет срабатывать таймер, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы если я задал выражение, то оно срабатывало именно каждые 3 дня, например начал с 23 января и соответственно следующие дни: 26 29 и 1 февраля.
Можно ли так реализовать и как?
Была идея сделать через минуты, то есть `*/4800 * * * *`, что в теории означало бы срабатывание каждый 3 день в 8:00

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days

Comment: @PavelGridin окэ, фенкс

Comment: не, `каждое 3 число месяца в 8:00` это - `0 8 3 * *`

Comment: @nörbörnën это будет только 3 число, а я имел ввиду каждое 3 число, то есть все числа кратные 3, это - 3,6,9,...,27,30

Comment: Добавить в скрипте проверку `[[ $(($(date +%j)%3)) -ne 0 ]] && exit` и запускать задание ежедневно не рассматриваете? UPD: перешел по первой ссылке, увидел такое решение уже предложили)

Comment: @PotroNik не хотелось бы запускать каждый день)

Comment: Понимаю, костыльное решение не всегда решение, но ответ я на всякий случай расписал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного распишу решение в случае если сдвиг выполнения скрипта в конце/начале года не устраивает.

Для этого в скрипте нужно зять большее значение, которое будет отсчитываться не зависимо от года или недели.

Поэтому берем секунды от **1970-01-01 00:00:00** командой `date +%s`

Получаем из этих секунд количество дней и выводим остаток от кратности 3

получаем команду:

```bsh
$((($(date +%s)/86400)%3))
```

Теперь можно создать команду запуска в кроне

```
0 8 * * * user /home/user/3day.sh(путь для примера) "/home/user/task/execute_script" "1"
```

где "/home/user/task/execute_script" - это путь к скрипту или программе, которые нужно запускать раз в три дня. А 1 - это цифра для сравнивая получаемого остатка

Далее наполнить скрипт /home/user/3day.sh следующим содержанием

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#Проверяем 1 параметр, если пусто выполнится echo
execute_line="${1:-echo Empty script}"
#Вторым параметром устанавливаем число остатка (0 до 2), день по которому выстраиваем интервал
#Если параметр не передан, берем 0 по умолчанию
interval=${2:-0}
if [[ $((($(date +%s)/86400)%3)) -eq $interval ]]; then
    #Выполняем переданную строку из первого параметра.
    $execute_line
fi
```

Не забыть выдать соответствующим группа и пользователям права на запуск /home/user/3day.sh

В итоге можно будет добавлять задания на разные дни с интервалом в 3 дня

```
 0 8 * * * user /home/user/3day.sh "/home/user/task/execute_script1"
 0 9 * * * user /home/user/3day.sh "/home/user/task/execute_script2" "1"
 0 10 * * * user /home/user/3day.sh "/home/user/task/execute_script3" "2"
```

Каждое из этих заданий будет выполняться раз в 3 дня, но пересечения между ними не будет