# Как реализовать linux скрипт останавливающий выполнение программы каждые три дня?

Tags: linux, bash

Здраствуйте.
Нужен скрипт работающий на Ubuntu 18.04 server, который завершает процесс по его имени или pid каждый третий день в 20.00 а через час запускает его снова.

Например 01.11.20 в 20.00 завершаем процесс sshd а через час, в 21.00 снова запускаем его.
Потом проделываем тоже самое 04.11.20, потом 07.11.20, потом 10.11.20 и тд...

Comment: Всё уже написано до нас. man 5 crontab + sleep в самом скрипте.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev cron разве может завершать работу скрипта? Это же планировщик.

Comment: Cron может запланировать запуск скрипта, убивающего процесс..

Comment: *как реализовать* — первым шагом надо было произвести декомпозицию поставленной перед вами задачи.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049232/341547 - про запуск именно с интервалом в 3 дня писал тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое в данном случае - использование планировщика cron.

Набираем в терминале `crontab -e` и вставляем в конец:

```
0 20 */3 * * скрипт остановки
0 21 */3 * * скрипт запуска
```

Вместо `скрипт остановки` и `скрипт запуска` прописываем ваши команды/скрипты соответственно.

*Стоит заметить, что в данном случае, запуски этих заданий будут производится в 20:00 и 21:00 в дни 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30.*

Если вам требуется запускать, останавливать службы, то я бы использовал `systemctl start/stop`. В остальных случаях, думаю, `kill`.

Советую на досуге прочитать про вышеупомянутые `kill`, `systemctl` и `cron`.

Comment: С февралём не очень получается...

Comment: @0andriy, согласен конечно, но если это не критично - то как вариант